# Creating a mapset and PERMANENT location for multiple GeoTIFF files in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, modis

I have a 2 year MODIS time series, with 45 files, all in tiff format. However, I don't know how to create a mapset for all files. I can only do it for one file. How do I create for my entire time series in GRASS GIS?

I'm Using GRASS on Windows.

This is my tif files

[image: My Tif Files]

I open grass gis and try to create a location for all files and click on the option read projection and datum terms a georeferenced datafile, but the option is one file at a time, I would like to create for all files at once.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the LOCATION and MAPSET only once, using only one of the files, then import all files into that LOCATION/MAPSET.

In addition, you can do this easily from the command line, using the `-e` parameter to the grass command. This parameter means "create location and exit". Then you restart GRASS in that LOCATION/MAPSET, and do your import of all files.

It would go something like this:

```
grass -e -c <"path/to/one/MODIS file"> <"path/to/your/GISDBASE/LOCATION/MAPSET">
```

Then start GRASS, choose that new LOCATION/MAPSET and do your import of all MODIS files.

Comment: In addition, you can also use the GUI for that, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Importing_data#Importing_multiple_raster_.28e.g..2C_GeoTIFF.29_files

Comment: thanks for help Micha !!